# Clustering or Grouping by list of similar strings

Tags: string-manipulation, data, cluster-analysis, gathering

I have gathered some sports data from over 40 different sources.  I now need to get all the games to "match up", "grouped", "clustered", or "aligned" so all the information for one game is in one list.  It is proving very challenging as there are many spellings for team names, leagues, and countries.

The data is a list of 4 strings in an association. The data structure is like this:

```
<|"awayTeamLookup" -> String||Missing[], "homeTeamLookup" -> String||Missing[], "countryLookup" -> String||Missing[], 
 "leaugeLookup" -> String||Missing[]|>
```

I have cleaned and standardized the strings with this function

```
TeamNameFix[teamName_] :=
 If[
  MissingQ[teamName],
  If[
   teamName === Missing[],
   Missing[],
   Missing[teamName]
   ],
  If[
   StringQ[teamName],
   StringJoin[
    Select[Characters[
      ToLowerCase[
       Transliterate[RemoveDiacritics[StringTrim[teamName]]]]], 
     LetterQ]],
   Missing[teamName]
   ]
  ]
```

A larger sample (2000 rows+) of the data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p3gK1Kp7vfz7Xv96KHPffsaWwS-V0lk6) in .wl format.

Here is a quick sample:

```
{<|dateMMA->{2020,2,20,21,30,0.},awayTeamLookup->northernarizona,homeTeamLookup->idahovandals,countryLookup->unitedstates,leaugeLookup->nationalcollegiateathleticassociationncaa|>,<|dateMMA->{2020,2,21,20,30,0.},awayTeamLookup->paraguay,homeTeamLookup->panama,countryLookup->international,leaugeLookup->americupqualification|>,<|dateMMA->{2020,2,20,13,15,0},awayTeamLookup->asvellyonvilleurbanne,homeTeamLookup->bcolympiakospiraeus,countryLookup->international,leaugeLookup->euroleague|>,<|dateMMA->{2020,2,20,20,0,0},awayTeamLookup->ncasheville,homeTeamLookup->radford,countryLookup->Missing[],leaugeLookup->ncaa|>,<|dateMMA->{2020,2,20,14,45,0.},awayTeamLookup->khimkimoscow,homeTeamLookup->olimpiamilano,countryLookup->Missing[],leaugeLookup->Missing[]|>}
```

I have tried a couple ways to do this to no avail.  There are 1000s of games at any one time so pattern matching I don't think will work.

1. `FindClusters[dataToGroup]`
2. `FindClusters[[[All,"awayTeamLookup"]]]` This only gives me games on the away team and the clusters are not all that great.
3. Finding the source with the most games and then, `Nearest[dataToGroup[[All,"awayTeamLookup"]],#]&/@longestSource[[All,"awayTeamLookup"]]`.  This only gives me games on the away team.  I guess I would need to do it on the other columns and then come up with an algo to combine them?  The algo should be smart enough that if the away team doesn't match up but the home team does, put those two games in a group.  Similarly with the league and country.